# Is there a way to save search results (i.e. allow user to re-enter/refresh url of search results) and still see results

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

Sorry if I explained it poorly. I'm very new to both Laravel and React and it would be best displayed through these examples. Essentially, I'm sending a search to Laravel from React:

```
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
        searchTerm: "",
        searchBy: "",
    });

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        post(route("searchCompletion", [data.searchTerm, data.searchBy]));
    };
```

The search term is the search term and the search method is either category or caption. I have a post route which works, but I'm trying to implement get so that I can re-retrieve the posts that are displayed (i.e. not get an error from http://localhost:8000/search/i?Caption=):

```
Route::post('/search/{searchTerm}', [SearchController::class, 'index'])->name('searchCompletion');
Route::get('/search/{searchTerm}', [SearchController::class, 'index'])->name('getSearchCompletion');
```

Also, here is my SearchController for reference:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $postsFromSearch = Post::latest()->get();
        $posts = [];

        $userArr = [];

        if ($request->searchBy == "Caption") {
            foreach($postsFromSearch as &$post) {
                if(str_contains($post->caption, $request->searchTerm)) {
                    array_push($posts, $post);
                    
                    array_push($userArr, $post->user->load('profile'));
                }
            }
        }

        return Inertia::render('Posts/Index')->with(compact(['posts', 'userArr']));



    }
}
```

How to re-render posts with url info.

Comment: Are you also using Inertia to tie Laravel and React together? This is what the Laravel starter kits, such as Breeze and Jetstream use.

Comment: Yes, I am using Inertia.